# Reading until the end of a line from a file and repeating the process for the successive line

Tags: c++

I'm working with this .txt file:

```
Anna 70 79 72 78 71 73 68 74 75 70
Jason 78 89 96 91 94 95 92 88 95 92
kim 83 81 93 85 84 79 78 90 88 79
Maria 93 100 86 99 98 97 96 95 94 92
```

I am storing the name in each line in a vector of struct that contains a string name and an int score. In the score I store te average of all numbers after the name (10 numbers / 10).

I've done all already and it's storing the first line with correct name and average score but what I am struggling with is to repeat this process for the following data. (Jason + his numbers, kim...)

```
struct Student
{
    string name;
    int score;
};

void printInfo(vector<Student>);


int main() {

    string defaultPath = "lab2.txt";
    ifstream inFile(defaultPath);

    vector<Student> studentData;

    string name;
    int score = 0, totalScore = 0, averageScore = 0;

    while (inFile >> name)
    {
        while (inFile >> score)
        {
            totalScore += score;
        }
        averageScore = totalScore / 10;
        studentData.push_back({name, averageScore});
    }

    cout << studentData[0].name << '\t' << studentData[0].score << endl;

}
```

Output of this code:

> Anna      73

(The name in the first line + average calculated)

`studentData[1].name / .score` has garbage on it.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current code is that when you read the scores you don't really know when the scores end. The loop will fail only when you read the next lines name, which will put the stream into an error state and no more will be read.

The way I propose that you solve your problem (and make the code more robust) is to

1. [Read line by line into a string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)
2. Put the string into an [input string stream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)
3. Read the name from the input string stream
4. Read the "scores" in a loop (like you do know) from the input string stream.
5. Done, onto the next line (go back to 1)

Other possible solutions is to clear any error state after reading the scores. Or use a `for` loop. Both of these requires you to hope that no line is malformed, or that there are no *real* errors reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the inner loop. When it fails to read a number, it will exit leaving the stream in an error state; which causes the outer loop to also fail.

Short of suggesting you use nested stringstreams, here is the easiest way to mitigate this problem:

```
while (inFile >> name)
{
    while (inFile >> score)
    {
        totalScore += score;
    }
    averageScore = totalScore / 10;
    studentData.push_back({name, averageScore});

    if (!inFile.eof()) {
        inFile.clear();
    }
}
```

This essentially clears any error states the stream might be in, but only does so as long as the [eof bit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) is not set.

---

- From running your code, I see you do not reset `totalScore` to zero before doing the next calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been pointed out by [@smac89's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54373899/434551). I want to suggest a slightly different answer.

1. Read lines of text untill there is nothing to read.
2. Process each line of text separately using a `std::istringstream`.

I would also suggest:

1. Declare variables only in the scope where they are needed.
2. Don't assume there are 10 numbers. Count the number of numbers successfully read and use the count to compute the average.

---

```
std::string line;
while (inFile >> line)
{
   std::string name;
   std::istringstream str(line);
   if ( !(str >> name) )
   {
      // Deal with error.
   }

   int count = 0;
   int score = 0;
   int totalScore = 0;
   while (str >> score)
   {
      totalScore += score;
      ++count;
   }

   if ( count > 0 )
   {
      int averageScore = totalScore / count;
      studentData.push_back({name, averageScore});
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an easy and useful way for you to use in the future :)

```
 #include <fstream>
 #include <sstream>

 struct Student
{
    string name;
    int score;
};

void printInfo(vector<Student>);

int main() {

    string defaultPath = "lab2.txt";
    ifstream inFile(defaultPath);

    vector<Student> studentData;
    string line;
    string name;
    string Sscore;
    int totalScore = 0, averageScore = 0;
    // first read the line
    while (getline(inFile,line))
    {
        totalScore = 0; averageScore = 0;
        stringstream temp(line);
        // read the first word which is delimited by a space

        getline(temp, name,' ');
        // read the rest words which are delimited by a space in the same line
        while (getline(temp, Sscore, ' '))
        {
            totalScore += atoi(Sscore.c_str());
        }
        averageScore = totalScore / 10;
        studentData.push_back({ name, averageScore });
    }

    cout << studentData[1].name << '\t' << studentData[1].score << endl;
    inFile.close();
}
```